# (jQuery) Different results based on checked attribute

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm wanting to change the background color on something depending on if it's child is checked or not, AND on whether or not it has the `checked='checked'` attribute in the HTML.

Basically, this is what I want:

- If it's checked by default (with `checked='checked'`) and the user unticks it, red background
- If it's checked by default, but no longer checked (user unticked it), but the user ticks it again, green background
- If it's unchecked by default, and the user checks it, blue background
- If it's unchecked by default, and the user checks it and then unchecks it, white background...

This is what I've got so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#memberForm input").change(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked") == true ) {
                $(this).closest('dt').css({"background" : "green"});
            }
            else {
                $(this).closest('dt').css({"background" : "red"}); }
        });
    });
```

I don't know how to incorporate the default value in the results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a class to all checked inputs on initial load:

```
$("input:checked").addClass("waschecked");
```

Then just check if that input has the class to tell if it was checked on initial load:

```
$(this).hasClass("waschecked")
```

Comment: I think that would be the best way to go.

Comment: This seems more like a workaround than an actual solution, but it seems simple and elegant. I'll wait for more solutions before deciding the answer. Thanks!

Comment: With 1.6 and the introduction of `prop`, I've read that `attr` should now do what you want, but in my tests it doesn't.  Not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried `attr`... is seems to act like `:checked` and checks to see if it's checked or not instead of if it has the actual attribute in the html... No worries tho, I've come to find that I actually really like this solution and it works well now. =D

Comment: In case anyone cares, I found the reason attr doesn't work as explained in the documentation of prop.  In the 1.6.1 notes:  "Specifically, boolean attributes such as checked, selected, readonly, and disabled in 1.6.1 will be treated just as they used to be treated in jQuery versions prior to 1.6."  So the statement in the prop docs was only true for 1.6 and reverted in 1.6.1.